# windows phone 7 script/interpreted available languages?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I found so far javascript and IronRuby is available? My main intention is to get information about available way to have run time execution in wp7 application. In other words I want to achieve dynamic behavior without recompiling my app. Wish to listen your input.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule this isn't available as if true dynamic behaviour was avbailable it would invalidate the purpose of having a certification process before being allowed into the marketplace.

If the logic of the app could be completely changed then the certification process would be pointless.